# How to keep a row as selected in typescript using option tag?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown as mentioned below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inertiaStart" style="float: left; width: 17%;">Inertia Start</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedShiftChannel" style="float: left; width: 70%;height: 26px;" (change)="onSelect($event, 'inertiaStart')">
            <option>RSH</option>
            <option *ngFor="let g of inertiaChannels" [value]="g">
                {{g}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

If the inertia channel name is "GAG", I want it to be selected. Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: You're combining AngularJS and Angular. That code won't work. Please read the official introduction tutorials on angular.io.

Comment: What does it mean " I want it to be selected" ? Please explain clearly

Comment: I want that value to be selected in the drop down and appear in the drop down box.

Comment: I want an example of using select tag to display a  dropdown and if drop down value matches some string, then it should be selected in the drop down box.

Comment: Or as straight forward as set the default value as "GAG" if the drop down list contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update below piece of code in Option.

```
<option *ngFor="let g of inertiaChannels" [value]="g" [selected]="g == 'GAG' ? true : false">
                {{g}}
</option>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?